# Div organization needed in order to achieve specific behavior

Tags: html

Please take a look at image below
All I want is somehow organize **Div** in order to achieve behavior drawn.
**Div 2** height can be dynamically changed and based on height I want containers to behave like i draw them.
The main problem that I encounter is that Div in this case will try to  force down both **Div 3** and **Div 4** (which is incorrect).
If this is not possible with **Div** only solution then maybe you can point at different container which can help here?, But still Div is proffered option.

[image: Div 2 resize]

**UPDATE**
This 2 cases should work as well.

[image: Div Update]

Comment: float, position and you are done

Comment: resizing 2 WILL move down 3 and 4. that's correct behavior. what you are doing however is against browser rules. try position absolute and some JS to determine if anything's underneath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <style>
    .container {width:601px;margin:50px auto;}
    .container div {border:1px solid black;overflow:hidden;height:200px;margin:0px -1px;}
    #div1 {width:400px;float:left;}
    #div2 {width:200px;float:right;height:300px;}
    #div3 {width:200px;float:left;}
    #div4 {width:400px;;float:right;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="div1">div 1</div>
            <div id="div2">div 2</div>
            <div id="div3">div 3</div>
            <div id="div4">div 4</div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: almost perfect actually :)
Please try setting height 100 or 500 , actually I don't want divs to move left or right...
+1 tough

Comment: Since there can't be better answer that this, marking this one as Answered, thanks.